# How to upload file in react?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, reactjs

I was trying to upload file in react, but failed because there was bad request.

Here are some codes.

```
uploadDoc = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
let file = e.target.files[0];
const url = 'https://api.agentcloud.com/api/leadfile/';
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('lead', this.props.match.params.id);
formData.append('file',file);
const config = {
    headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Token 90406829e9d311b117bb7e1484a81e7b7f9f4551'
    }
}
return  post(url, formData, config);
```

}

Comment: this may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeiOnkEI7XI

Answer (score 0):

Remove the content-type header, its incomplete.
When you use a form data object for ajax a proper content-type header is generated for you.¹

¹. I don't know react so this might only be part of the problem.